# FacesComponent funciona en una página pero no en el resto (recupera null de un evento ajax)

Tags: jsf

No sé si hay una respuesta a esta pregunta en el foro, pero no he sido capaz de encontrarla.

Estoy creando un composite component con dos SelectOneMenu que ejecutan un evento ajax cuando hay un cambio en el item seleccionado.

El componente funciona dentro de un página, pero si lo añado a otras, no lo hace. En todas las demás páginas, el valor que se recupera del SelectOneMenu es un "null".

```
 //Enp001DatosNotificacion.xhtml, recupera el valor seleccionado del SelectOneMenu (b, por ejemplo)
 //En el resto recupera un valor "null"

 UISelectOne oneVoewl = (UISelectOne)event.getSource();
 System.out.println("One Voewl > " + oneVoewl.getValue());
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar y decirme qué puedo estar haciendo mal?

Gracias !

### El código

***Component backing bean***

```
@FacesComponent(value="letterExample")
public class LetterExample extends UINamingContainer{

    public void voewlAjaxListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
        UISelectOne oneVoewl = (UISelectOne)event.getSource();
        System.out.println("One Voewl > " + oneVoewl.getValue());

    }
```

***Composite component*** (*Nota: Estoy usando un bean existente para hacer las pruebas*)

```
<cc:interface componentType="letterExample" >
    <cc:attribute name="bean" type="es.ccasa.sgnx.business.bean.Direccion" />
</cc:interface>


<cc:implementation>

    <p:selectOneMenu id="oneMenuVoewl" value="#{cc.attrs.bean.codigoPais}" 
        binding="#{cc.uiSelectOneVoewl}" >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Aaaa" itemValue="a" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Eeee" itemValue="e" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Iiii" itemValue="i" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Oooo" itemValue="o" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Uuuu" itemValue="u" />
        <p:ajax event="change"  listener="#{cc.voewlAjaxListener}" update="consonantsWrapper" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <h:panelGroup id="consonantWrapper" layout="block">
        <p:selectOneMenu id="oneMenuConsonant"  value="#{cc.attrs.bean.codigoProvincia}"
            binding="#{cc.uiSelectOneConsonant}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Bbbb" itemValue="b" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Cccc" itemValue="c" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Dddd" itemValue="d" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>

    </h:panelGroup>

</cc:implementation>
```

***Bean***

```
public class Direccion implements Serializable {
    private String codigoPais; /* with its getter and setter*/
    private String codigoProvincia; /* with its getter and setter*/

}
```

***XHTML*** 
Así es como lo tengo dentro de las páginas: (El nombre del controller es el del controlador de la página)

```
<sgnx:letter-example bean="#{controller.direccion}" />
```

***The @Named beans***

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class P001DatosNotificacionController
    private Direccion direccion; /* with its getter and setter*/

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class P001GestionNotificacionesController
    private Direccion direccion; /* with its getter and setter*/

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class P002BandejaProvisionalNotificacionesController
    private Direccion direccion; /* with its getter and setter*/
```

Comment: No entiendo que quieres decir con `pero si lo añado a más`

Comment: Quiero decir que si ese mismo componente lo añado a otros xhtml, el evento ama no recupera el valor selecionado. Devuelve null.

Comment: El componente está en 3 xhtml distintos. Pero solamente (teniendo lo mismo en los 3 controladores) funciona en uno.

Comment: ¿Te da algún error? Ponte un punto de ruptura en UISelectOne oneVoewl = (UISelectOne)event.getSource(); y mira a ver que te devuelve...

Comment: @alex Es lo primero que hice pensando que no recuperaba el objeto UISelectOneMenu, pero lo recupera.
De hecho, cuando se dispara el evento de cambio, y pasa por el método validate del SelectOneMenu(UIInput) y hace un setValue del nuevo valor (_newValue contiene el valor seleccionado de pantalla_)

        if (isValid()) {
            Object previous = getValue();
            setValue(newValue); 
            setSubmittedValue(null);
            if (compareValues(previous, newValue)) {
                queueEvent(new ValueChangeEvent(this, previous, newValue));
            }
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de un par de semanas he retomado de nuevo el problema. 
He empezado desde el principio.

Cuando he empezado a escribir el código del controlador y he anotado el bean con 
`@ViewScoped` me han aparecido para importar dos paquetes distintos `javax.faces.bean` y `javax.faces.view`

Ese era el fallo. Estaba usando una combinación de paquetes errónea:

```
import javax.inject.Named;    
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
```

Así que la solución ha sido tan sencilla como usar los paquetes adecuadamente:

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
```

En estos posts están las preguntas y respuestas al problema:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251176/viewscoped-bean-recreated-on-every-postback-request-when-using-jsf-2-2
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921324/managedproperty-in-cdi-named-bean-returns-null
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516750/inject-cdi-bean-into-jsf-viewscoped-bean